# Single Tree detection in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, raster-calculator, spatial-statistics, feature-extraction

I was wondering how I could extract "crown area" of single trees in a forest from a high-resolution image with only 3 band (RGB) in ArcMap. ( No NIR to use NDVI as any threshold).

I need a fast easy-to-do way to come up with a shapefile with polygons (made of several pixels depending on size of each individual tree).
Here was I was thinking : Focal Statistic - Conditional (Raster calculator)- Extracr Attributes- Convert to polygon

I just need trees (to calculate their diameter at the end) in the forest. No matter the species or whatever.

I am using eCognition but I want to try ArcMap/ ( It's ok if its not 100% accurate!!! )

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot showing the type of trees and surrounding vegetation?  What type of 3-band imagery are you using? What is the spatial resolution?

Comment: Its just an image taken from Google-earth! There is just one type of species but surrounding areas are mainly bare land, bareland+grass and some urban areas  which I am not interested in any of them!  I just want to throw away any none-tree objects and then find the CPA.

Comment: Have you tried calculating any texture metrics in eCognition?

Comment: Nope! I used brightness and Mean-Layer 2  for classification of shadow, forest, bareland, ...I wanted to extract polygons as trees to ArcMap  but then it wasn't giving good results. Now I just want to use ArcMap to find trees(brighter and higher in pixel value) and make polygons for each single one.

Comment: Focal Statistic - Conditional (Raster calculator)- Extract Attributes- Convert to polygon.... This one works somehow but the final polygons are not exactly matching the tree-positions!  It needs serious improvements!

Comment: If there are tree shadows in the scene and the trees have an open canopy, you may be able to identify the trees by the tree shadows.

Comment: Have you considered a quick search with Google, there are quite a few papers written on using satellite imagery using texture as a way of extracting trees. Have a look [here](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=image+texture+tree+identification+australia&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5)