# Generating Canopy Height Model (CHM) with Quick Terrain Modeler?

Tags: dem, lidar, forest-ecology, canopy-height-model, quick-terrain-modeler

I currently looking forward to process LiDAR point clouds (forest data) using Quick Terrain Modeler (QTM), but is it possible to create Canopy Height Model directly using the software?

Comment: Can CHM be performed from RGB generated Ortho and DSM in QGIS ?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a Canopy Height Model (CHM), subtract the DEM from a DSM using the `Subtract Model` tool:

[image]

Take a look at [Quick Terrain Modeler: Importing LAS to DEM/DSM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnSkAwZerpM) tutorial. The part you are interested begins in 4:58, but I advise watching the full video (the above picture was taken from it).

I also find the [Quick Terrain Modeler: Above Ground Analysis](http://appliedimagery.com/tutorials/above-ground-level-agl-analysis/) tutorial useful, because it teaches to build a Digital Elevation Models from both unclassified and classified point clouds, and then, to [normalize](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112587/normalizing-point-cloud-data/113125#113125) points using the created DEM. The 'DSM' resulting from a normalized point cloud is the CHM.

In case one is confused about the DEM or DSM terminology, I suggest reading [What is the difference between DEM, DSM and DTM?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-is-the-difference-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm/57306#57306)

---

About if "QTM can be an autonomous processing software for biomass estimation of the forest":

Usually, when working with LiDAR data aiming to estimate forest biomass (both through an area-based approach or a single-tree approach) there will be more than one software involved. Hence, QTM won't work for performing all necessary steps (for example, tree segmentation). For the latter, take a look at:

[Extracting tree crown areas from remote sensing data (visual images and LiDAR)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124224/extracting-tree-crown-areas-from-remote-sensing-data-visual-images-and-lidar)

What I usually do when modelling forest biomass is to use a statistic software such as R, and call other tools for processing LiDAR data from there. For example, see [Retrieving LiDAR metrics from relative vertical layers of point cloud](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183924/retrieving-lidar-metrics-from-relative-vertical-layers-of-point-cloud/184658#184658).

Comment: Can this software perform single tree segmentation ?

Comment: as far as i know, the software is limited to certain extend only and for further analysis, we have to proceed to other GIS software; ArcGIS for example

Comment: @FarhanRajuli, I complimented my answer to explain what I do in terms of software used when modelling forest biomass with LiDAR data. Best.